# CSS Body background-color doesn't work?

Tags: html, css

I'm assuming this is a super simple issue, but I'm staring blankly at my screen trying to figure this out. I'm trying to change some things of the body of my html document, but nothing changes?

```css
@charset "utf-8";
body
{
    background-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Statistics</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"
 integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-default-outline">View All</button>  
</body>
</html>
```

If i change the background image, it works fine. Any idea why? Could it be the bootstrap css?

Comment: Yes, something is rewriting your css rules, you can force `aqua` with `!important` : `background-color: aqua !important`.

Comment: Order matters in CSS, the bootstrap css is setting a background color that overrides the one in your CSS. Change the order in which the css files are included.

Comment: Thanks! That fixed it

Comment: Don't leave your code with an !important flag, Use your browser developer tools / inspector to see whats overwriting the styles of that element.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

if you add !important after "aqua", does it work?

```
@charset "utf-8";
body
{
    background-color: aqua !important;
}
```

If yes, then there's probably some other styles, like the bootstrap.css interfering.

You also should put your custom css file *after* the bootstrap-css.

Comment: and ... if no ?

Comment: @Eregrith then it's not due to other css files